# Do all flash memory chips pinout layout and usage follow a specific standar(s) and protocols?

Tags: protocol, flash-memories

As I see in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/553602/181499) I see that WINDBOND W25Q128FV has similar pin inteface/layout with the Maxronix MX35LF1GE4AB.

Therefore, the following question came to my mind, do all flash memory chip follow same pin layout/usage and signaling. I mean, if I take a random usb memory stick can I just replace it flash memory chip with another one and work out of the box?

Also, is there some sort of standard, when an MCU/CPU interfaces a flash memory chip regardless of its origin?

Comment: why would you expect `similar` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No official standard for pinout OR protocol other than they are often made to fall into one of several loosely similar groups to ease interchangeability (but not to make it mindless). Interchangeable must be determined on a case-by-case basis.

You also talk about flash as if there was no such thing as parallel vs serial flash. USB sticks definitely do do not use serial flash and most microcontrollers are used with serial flash ICs.